# ImportError: No module named 'tkinter' after pyInstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller, importerror

I want to do an executable, but ervery time I run the .exe it writes `ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'`, and all I read on Stackowerflow do not help me !

My python program is simple (ODE solver) and requests only :

```
from math import*
from pylab import*
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I paste a copy of my `prog.py` into the `C:\Python\Scripts` folder where pyInstaller is. I compute the command line `pyinstaller -F eulersolver.py`, this creates a `prog.exe` in the `dist` folder. When I run this code I have

```
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'
Failed to execute script prog
```

But my program do not use this module... do you have any proposition or help for me ?

**OS :** Windows64

**Python :** 3.5 for Win64

**Note :** I already unistall/install python 3 times today (after reading documentation on this webside and abroad).

**Note 2 :** I use Python only for scientific issues. I am no computer scientist, so be kind to me when explaining computer stuff :S

Comment: EDIT (because I cannot edit my own post -_-) : the command line is actually `pyinstaller -F prog.py`

Comment: `matplotlib` use `tkinter` to display window with plot.

Comment: try to `import tkinter` maybe then it assign tkinter module too. Or read how to set config before you run `pyinstaller`. `tkinter` uses external `dll` with language `tcl` and its gui `tk` so maybe you have to manually add to config information about `tcl.dll` and `tk.dll` (I don't use Windows so I don't know if it is `tcl.dll` and `tk.dll`)

Comment: Did that, but the same result when importing tkinter :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyInstaller - no module named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/pyinstaller-no-module-named)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use hidden import
`pyinstaller eulersolver.py --hidden-import=tkinter -y`

Answer (score 4):

FINALLY WORKED FOR `pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=tkinter --hidden-import=tkinter.filedialog prog.py` Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that pyinstaller won't see **second level  imports**. So if you import module *A*, pyinstaller sees this. But any additional module that is imported in *A* will not be seen.

There is no need to change anything in your python scripts. You can directly add the missing imports to the **spec file** (*prog.spec* in your case).
Just change the following line:

```
hiddenimports=[],
```

to

```
hiddenimports=["tkinter"],
```

After that run `pyinstaller prog.spec` to create the *prog.exe*.