# ImportError: No module named face_recognition after running windows executable file.

Tags: python, pyinstaller, face-recognition, wine

It is basically on face recognition API.

I successfully installed dlib and face_recognition API from this [Repo](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition), It works more accurately as mentioned in Git-hub repository, I made some modification in the python program and it is giving expected output what i needed. I totally executed in ubuntu OS 16.04

For which i made some modification in python program. My thought was to generate windows executable file for the same.

Python file consist of Import functions like face_recognition, numpy and os.

I have used PyInstaller under WINE to generate windows executable file.

When I run ".exe" file in windows machine, I am getting error like this

**G:\file>all_modified.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "all_modfied.py", line 2, in 
ImportError: No module named face_recognition
[7180] Failed to execute script all_modified**

Solution which I tried is Installing Face_recognition module in windows machine but got same error as above.

Any Help will be greatly Appreciated :) Thank you.

Comment: [No module named when using PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40484001)

Answer (score 0):

Put face_recognition folder in your exe files . You can find this folder in your virtual environment scripts library folder , and don't use wine . Simply run pyinstaller your_file.py --onefile(for single exe)

or

pyinstaller your_file.py (for one directory)