# Trouble using PyInstaller in Ubuntu

Tags: python, tesseract, pyinstaller, python-tesseract

I have a python application where I'm using [tesserocr](https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/), [ocrmypdf](https://pypi.org/project/ocrmypdf/). I am trying to create a stand-alone executable of it by using [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org).

I can successfully create the executable by using the following command

```
$ pyinstaller -F --clean code.py
```

But when I run it

```
$ ./code
```

I get this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tesserocr'
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocrmypdf'

**code.py**

```
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI
import ocrmypdf

...
```

I have cross checked `tesserocr` and `ocrmypdf` are successfully installed in my system.

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862192/6560549

Comment: @SuperShoot But `import ocrmypdf` is not a second level import

Comment: Well I did say 'possibly' ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
pyinstaller -F --clean code.py --hidden-import='tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI' --hidden-import='ocrmypdf'
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the command you suggested but problem persists