# creating .exe file with scipy interpolate module

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, pyinstaller

I have created a script with a single line:
'from scipy import interpolate'.
This script runs OK on both Spyder and PyCharm.
I tried to create an .exe file from this script using pyinstaller. The executable file is created, but running it gives an error: 'The specified module cannot be found.'
The executable file size is 103MB, and it took a while to create. I am running Windows 10 and Python 3.7.
[Somebody else also complained about this a few months ago.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/PyInstaller/interpolate$20module/pyinstaller/Nz0i24EIsYE/gIUc8TbHAAAJ)

Comment: It sounds like pyinstaller environment and the environment you run the exe file differs. Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25733467/448625

Comment: The problem disappeared. I have no idea why.