Problem when adding dependencies to pyinstaller using poetry to manage dependencies
I am attempting to create an executable file in Windows 10 Pro from a python script that uses import
# main.py
from termcolor import cprint

def main() -> None:
    cprint('Hello', 'red')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I have installed poetry  and created an environment
 poetry new test 

added termcolor
poetry add termcolor

If I enter the poetry shell and run the script
python main.py

it works as expected.
When I create the exe
pyinstaller --onefile main.py

and try to run the exe it generates  ModuleNotFoundError for termcolor
This is my main.spec file
a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=['.', 'C:\Users\... path to ...\site-packages'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
)

What am I doing wrong?

you can try adding termcolor to hidden imports in your spec file

this may also be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/no-module-named-when-using-pyinstaller

@iBeMeltin That question is confused - hidden imports doesn't help

Look at HBKs answer. That involves poetry module as well

@iBeMeltin Thanks - I like the discipline of envs - This is my first foray into Windows and I don't want my global python contaminated by lots of (possibly conflicting) additional modules. I'll investigate further - I can see why poetry might be a problem

This answer might be a place to start

I solved this issue based on this answer. I give the details of my solution in detail in the hope that it might help someone in the future.
As we're using poetry to manage the environment, we need to run pyinstaller as a script  defined in  the pyproject.toml tool.poetry.scripts section (see below). It will not work if you call it directly from the command line.
Create a new project
poetry new xyz


in the projects directory and it creates
.
└─projects
    └─xyz
        ├── xyz
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├─── tests 
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── pyproject.toml
        └── README.md

In the lower of the two xyz directories create your main.py and  pyinstaller.py
# xyz/xyz/pyinstaller.py
import PyInstaller.__main__
from pathlib import Path

HERE = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
path_to_main = str(HERE / "main.py")

def install():
    PyInstaller.__main__.run([
        path_to_main,
        '--onefile',
        '--windowed',
        # other pyinstaller options...
    ])

In the pyproject.toml file add the lines
[tool.poetry.scripts]
build = "xyz.pyinstaller:install"

Enter the new project's directory
cd xyz

Then enter poetry shell
poetry shell

and add PyInstaller
poetry add PyInstaller

Add any other dependencies
poetry add <dependencies ...>

Build the application
poetry run build

(Caveat you might get a virus warning - if so, exclude your xyz folder in Windows security)
